# How to clear the queue_messages objects from the MSDB?

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation that MSDB consuming around 70 disk space on the drive, and we found that the Queue_messages object is consuming the disk space.
we tried shrinking the database but still no luck, is there an option to clear the queue_messages objects from the MSDB so that i can create a free disk space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sent a lot of mail that wasn't delivered, apparently. Check out this article on how to troubleshoot e-mail delivery:

[Troubleshooting Database Mail: Mail queued, not delivered](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190630.aspx)

Comment: Hi Roger. It would be good to expand on the that and quote some relevant steps from that link.